# Java repaint() acting different in listeners than in rest of code

Tags: java, swing, listener, repaint

When I start the program everything in one panel is rendered with 0,0 at the edge of the frame  however when I repaint in a listener (no where else in the code works) it positions 0,0 at the edge of the panel. If I remove everything from the panel that moves then it renders the first panel twice. This is a problem as the first time a listener is performed everything moves down

I would post a picture but I do not have enough reputation so I shall attempt to make a diagram using text

1 = panel1
2 = panel1 clone
0 = panel2 0,0
3 = panel2
x = blank

befor click:
0111111
3333333
3333333

after click with panel2:
1111111
0333333
3333333

after click without panel2:
1111111
0222222
XXXXXXX

The class with the broken panel is TestPanel
This is the class that calls TestPanel:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Paint;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Drawer {

    Images i;

    protected JPanel p = new JPanel();
    protected JPanel map = new JPanel();
    protected JPanel test = new JPanel();
    protected JPanel test2 = new JPanel();

    protected World world;

    protected TestPanel test3;

    public Drawer(Images i, Keying k, Main main){
        world = new World();
        test3 = new TestPanel(i, main);
        this.i = i;
        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        BoxLayout mapLayout = new BoxLayout(map, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS);
        map.setLayout(mapLayout);
        map.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1, Color.BLACK, Color.GRAY));
        map.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        MapComp mc1 = new MapComp(2);
        mc1.setType(1);
        MapButton mb1 = new MapButton(new Level(), 2);
        MapComp mc2 = new MapComp(2);
        MapButton mb2 = new MapButton(new Level(), 2);
        MapComp mc3 = new MapComp(2);

        map.add(mc1);

        for(Level l:world.levels){
            if(l.getStatus()!=Level.STATUS_UNPLAYED){
                map.add(l.mapButton);
                if(l.getStatus()!=Level.STATUS_NEXT){
                    MapComp m = new MapComp(2);
                    m.setType(0);
                    map.add(m);
                }
            }
        }


//      map.add(mb1);
//      map.add(mc2);
//      map.add(mb2);
//      map.add(mc3);

        map.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());


        GridLayout testLayout = new GridLayout(8,8);
        test.setLayout(testLayout);
        test.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1, Color.BLACK, Color.GRAY));
        test.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(30));

        GridLayout test2Layout = new GridLayout(8,8);
        test2.setLayout(test2Layout);
        test2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1, Color.BLACK, Color.GRAY));
        test2.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(30));
        test2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        test3.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
        test3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1, Color.BLACK, Color.GRAY));

        p.add(map);

        p.add(test3);

        System.out.println(mb1.getLevel().printStatus());

        Saver.createFilleStructure();
        //world.l1.save();

        //switchComponant(test, test2);
    }

    public int getIndex(JComponent comp){
        return p.getComponentZOrder(comp);
    }

    public void switchComponant(JComponent oldComp, JComponent newComp){
        int i = p.getComponentZOrder(oldComp);
        p.remove(i);
        p.add(newComp, i);

    }
}
```

This class has the paintcomponent method

```
package main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

    Images i;
    //Dimension size = new Dimension(32, 32);
    //  Point[][] points = new Point[(int) size.getWidth()][(int) size.getHeight()];

    World w = new World();



    Tiles tiles = new Tiles();

    int scale = 1;

    Point offset = new Point(0, 0);

    public boolean smooth;

    Dimension levelSize = new Dimension();


    public TestPanel(Images i, Main m){
        this.i = i;
        w.setCurrentLevel(w.levels.get(0));

        repaint();

        //Random ranGen = new Random();
        //      for(int x=0;x<(int) size.getWidth();x++){
        //          for(int y=0;y<(int) size.getHeight();y++){
        //              points[x][y] = new Point(7 - (((y+((int) x/8))^2) % 8), 7 - (((x+((int) y/8))^2) % 8));
        //              System.out.println(points[x][y].x + ", " + points[x][y].y);
        //          }
        //      }
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
        requestFocusInWindow();
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                requestFocusInWindow();
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W){
                    if(offset.getY()<0){
                        offset.y+=1;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("can not move");
                    }
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S){
                    if(offset.getY()<levelSize.getWidth()*32){
                        offset.y-=1;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("can not move");
                    }
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){
                    if(offset.getX()<0){
                        offset.x+=1;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("can not move");
                    }
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D){
                    if(offset.getX()<levelSize.getHeight()*32){
                        offset.x-=1;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("can not move");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        Level l = w.getCurrentLevel();
        levelSize.setSize(l.width, l.height);
        scale = 1;
        while(l.width*32*scale<getWidth() || l.height*32*scale<getHeight()){
            scale+=1;
        }
        for(int x=0;x<(int) l.width;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<(int) l.height;y++){
                if((x*32+((int)offset.getX())+32)*scale>=0 && (x*32+32+((int)offset.getX())-32)*scale<=getWidth() && (y*32+((int)offset.getY())+32)*scale>=0 && (y*32+((int)offset.getY())-32)*scale<=getHeight()){
                    Tile t = tiles.getTileById(l.levelData[x][y].getId());
                    AffineTransform af = new AffineTransform();
                    af.rotate((Math.PI/2)*l.levelData[x][y].getRotation(), (x*32+16+((int)offset.getX()))*scale, (y*32+16+((int)offset.getY()))*scale);
                    g2D.setTransform(af);
                    g2D.drawImage(t.getImage(), (x*32+((int)offset.getX()))*scale, (y*32+((int)offset.getY()))*scale, (x*32+32+((int)offset.getX()))*scale, (y*32+32+((int)offset.getY()))*scale, 0, 0, 32, 32, null);
                    g2D.setTransform(new AffineTransform());
                    for(OverlayData overlay:l.levelData[x][y].getOverlayData()){
                        Tile t2= tiles.getTileById(overlay.getId());
                        int corner = overlay.isCorner()? 1 : 0;
                        if(t2.hasImage){
                            g2D.drawImage(t2.getOverlayImage(), (x*32+((int)offset.getX()))*scale, (y*32+((int)offset.getY()))*scale, (x*32+32+((int)offset.getX()))*scale, (y*32+32+((int)offset.getY()))*scale, overlay.getMod()*32, corner*32, overlay.getMod()*32+32, corner*32+32, null);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should override `paintComponent` in swingComponent rather than `paint` and you should call `super.paint..` in first line. Read more [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: `Swing programs should override paintComponent() instead of overriding paint(). Although the API allows it, there is generally no reason to override paintBorder() or paintComponents() (and if you do, make sure you know what you're doing!).`

Comment: @nachokk I changed to paintComponent() but all this did was outline that the problem was that the panel is displayed in the wrong place. I also tried the super.paint() method however this caused errors (at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
 at main.TestPanel.paintComponent(TestPanel.java:104)) and nothing being rendered

Comment: `super.paintComponent(g)` you have to call!!!

Comment: Ok, that didn't cause errors but didn't solve the initial problem at hand either. Thanks anyway @nachokk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not possible to easily test this based on the posted code, it's very likely that this is caused by the call to `Graphics2D#setTransform`.

Quoting from the JavaDoc:

*Overwrites the Transform in the Graphics2D context. WARNING: This method should **never** be used to apply a new coordinate transform on top of an existing transform because the Graphics2D might already have a transform that is needed for other purposes, such as rendering Swing components or applying a scaling transformation to adjust for the resolution of a printer.*

*To add a coordinate transform, use the transform, rotate, scale, or shear methods. The setTransform method is intended only for restoring the original Graphics2D transform after rendering, as shown in this example:*

```
// Get the current transform 
AffineTransform saveAT = g2.getTransform(); 
// Perform transformation 
g2d.transform(...); 
// Render 
g2d.draw(...); 
// Restore original transform 
g2d.setTransform(saveAT);
```

EDIT: An attempt to apply this pattern to your for-loop, where you called `setTransform`, could *roughly* look like this:

```
// Store the original transform
AffineTransform oldAT = g2D.getTransform();

for(int x=0;x<(int) l.width;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<(int) l.height;y++){
        if((x*32+((int)offset.getX())+32)*scale>=0 && (x*32+32+((int)offset.getX())-32)*scale<=getWidth() && (y*32+((int)offset.getY())+32)*scale>=0 && (y*32+((int)offset.getY())-32)*scale<=getHeight()){
            Tile t = tiles.getTileById(l.levelData[x][y].getId());

            // Apply the rotation to the g2D directly
            g2D.rotate((Math.PI/2)*l.levelData[x][y].getRotation(), (x*32+16+((int)offset.getX()))*scale, (y*32+16+((int)offset.getY()))*scale);
            g2D.drawImage(t.getImage(), (x*32+((int)offset.getX()))*scale, (y*32+((int)offset.getY()))*scale, (x*32+32+((int)offset.getX()))*scale, (y*32+32+((int)offset.getY()))*scale, 0, 0, 32, 32, null);

            // "Undo" the rotation by restoring the original transform
            g2D.setTransform(oldAT);
            for(OverlayData overlay:l.levelData[x][y].getOverlayData()){
                Tile t2= tiles.getTileById(overlay.getId());
                int corner = overlay.isCorner()? 1 : 0;
                if(t2.hasImage){
                    g2D.drawImage(t2.getOverlayImage(), (x*32+((int)offset.getX()))*scale, (y*32+((int)offset.getY()))*scale, (x*32+32+((int)offset.getX()))*scale, (y*32+32+((int)offset.getY()))*scale, overlay.getMod()*32, corner*32, overlay.getMod()*32+32, corner*32+32, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Finally, restore the original transform again
g2D.setTransform(oldAT);
```

There may be more elegant solutions, though....

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine. As you may be able to tell from the rest of the code posted I'm just looking for things to work elegancy can come later.